# iOS ViewController uilabel only updates on rotation in tab bar application

Tags: ios, rotation, uilabel, viewcontroller

I am new to iOS development and trying to figure out what is happening here. I have a tab bar application with multiple ViewControllers and classes. One of my classes is called and updates the uilabels which works fine. Another class is then called which also runs a background loop which is intended to update some other uilabels on the same ViewController, they are updated once with the first entry from the loop and but not while the loop remains running in the background. I can see the loop is still running and the details are changing as I am logging the output using NSLog.

The ViewController also supports rotation, if I rotate the screen the number in the loop is then drawn to the uilabel and is fixed until I rotate the screen again, ie if I set the loop to count to 5 and then reset, depending where in the loop I rotate the screen will depend which number between 1 and 5 is drawn to the uilabel.

On a single ViewController application this is working fine, the loop runs and the uilabels are updated live as expected.

The classes to update the uilabels are called from [super viewDidLoad].

Thanks

**Here is the class with the loop :-**

```
 + (void)Loop:(FirstViewController *)vc

 {
 NSLog(@"start");


    static NSUInteger counter1 = 0;
    NSLog(@"with count %d", counter1);

    counter1++;
    NSLog(@"count ++ %d", counter1);

    NSString *label01 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", counter1];

    //update uilabel
    vc.cha01.text = label01;

            if (counter1 >= 5) {

                            counter1 = 0;

                            }


      // run loop with 1 second delay
      [self performSelector:@selector(Loop:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop is wrong, in the first go you pass the viewController but when you call the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` you are passing `nil`.

Thus the `vc` parameter will be `nil`, just pass the `vc` parameter:

```
   // run loop with 1 second delay
  [self performSelector:@selector(Loop:) withObject:vc afterDelay:1];
```

Just a tip, you should use a custom object to hold you data, then in the `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` read out the values and set the labels. 
A `UIViewController` can unload to free up memory and this could cause problems with you code.

Just use an MVC solution,thus a model which holds you data, strings in your case. Then set the label, the view part of MVC, in the de `UIViewController`, the controller in MVC.

---

<strike>Once a view is loaded the `-(void)viewDidLoad` is never called again. This goes for all your views in the `UITabBarController`.</strike>

You should move the code that updates the labels to the `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Comment: That worked, thanks very much.   I will look at your other suggestion too and see how I can optimise the code.